# Feeding Asp.net application in real time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, real-time

I have a web application that will have backend written asp.net mvc4 and expose to client with rest [web-api](http://www.asp.net/web-api). What I would like is that ability to feed that application from web service in real time. (Web service returns xml/json format which is not that big object). There are couple of options here : (of course node.js, tornado will be better alternatives here but backend should be on asp.net/iis stack)

1. Feeding data object directly from service to middle-tier by binding
   event, and when event handled persisting data to database. (instead
   of first persisting then polling)
2. Creating [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) object
       and register event to notify app when there is a update(possibly
       insert) in specific table.

Probable stack : Asp.net MVC4 + Web API + IIS + Sql Server 2008 + C#

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a "Node.js" but on the microsoft stack check out SignalR from NuGet - it offers evry similar functionality to Node.js but is native to the .NET stack! http://nuget.org/packages/SignalR

As an aside SignalR isn't just "node for ASP.NET" but it seems like the perfect fit for your requirements ;o) Loads of resources out there on Google for SignalR too!

Comment: Yeah I am looking it right now. Any metric on how this scale on microsoft stack ? Most of the connections in my app may sitting idle for a while by the way(Link : http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx to article)

Comment: Check this stack post for convo on scalability - includes link to a channel 9 video on the subject http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700944/is-signalr-stable-and-scalable-enough-for-high-traffic-production-environments Seems to scale well from my skim reading. I'm dying to play with this - just waiting for a project to pop-along that requires it ;o)

Answer (score 2):

Before you read the rest, a disclaimer: I work for Realtime.co but I do believe I can help here so I'm not trying to "pitch a sale".

If you need to have real time updates, you can check out Realtime (www.realtime.co). It's basically a set of tools for developers to use real time technologies on their projects. It uses websockets but does fallback to whatever the user's browser supports (such as long polling, for example). There's a ASP.Net API too which you can use in your project.

You can learn more about Realtime at www.realtime.co and get to know the developer/SDK layer at www.xrtml.org.

I hope that helps.